# <li> overlapping <ul> on hover

Tags: css, hover, html-lists, submenu

I have a subnav menu that appears on hover over the parent menu item. All functions as expected, except that padding applied to the `<li>` pushes content beyond the edge of the containing `<ul>`.

I played with floats, clears and width settings, but none have delivered the desired result. The closest I've come is to apply float:left to the `<li>`, with `width:100%`.

With this, however, something innexplicable occurs. There are three parent items that include submenus. The parent menu is inline, while the submenu is block.

With the third submenu, meaning that which appears farthest to the right in relation to the inline menu, the styles described above do not take effect. Instead, its appearance remains as it is currently, with the `<li>` pushing beyond the containing `<ul>`. Totally strange.

The code follows -- you can see the menu in action at [revo.wesleypicote.com](http://revo.wesleypicotte.com)

HTML

```
<ul class="mainNavContainer clearfix">

    <li class="mainNavRows navParents active current">

        <a href="page/">Page</a>

    <ul class="subNavContainer">

        <li class="subNavRows"><a href="subPage 1">subPage 1</a></li>

        <li class="subNavRows"><a href="subPage 2">subPage 2</a></li>...

    </ul>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Styles

```
/* styles for mobile menu */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { display: table; content: ""; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }


.mainNavContainer {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3000;
        display: inline-block;
        border-top: dotted 1px #E6E6E6;
        border-bottom: dotted 1px #E6E6E6;
    }

/* make the dropdown ul invisible */

#mainNav ul li ul.subNavContainer {
    display: none;
    }

/* make the sub menu ul visible and position it beneath the main menu list item */

#mainNav ul li:hover ul.subNavContainer {
    display:block !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto !important;
    top:32px;
    background-image:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0 0 2% 0;
    }

#mainNav ul li ul.subNavContainer {
    width: auto !important;
    }

/* style the background and foreground color of the submenu links */

#mainNav .subNavContainer {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:#FFF; 
        color:#A8A8A8;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }

#mainNav ul li ul.subNavContainer li.subNavRows {
    display:block;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    width:auto !important;
    margin:0;
    padding:2% 0;
        background-image:none;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #E6E6E6;
    }

#mainNav ul.subNavContainer li.subNavRows:hover {
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    }

#mainNav ul.subNavContainer li.subNavRows a {
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5%;
    font-size:.85em;
    color:#A8A8A8;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove every occurrence of `width: auto !important;`
2. use `#mainNav > ul` instead of `#mainNav ul`  (this means that your css will apply only for the first occurrence of the ul, under the #mainNav, it's a good practice to use it cause main nav style can have impact on the subnav otherwise)

For having submenu that will strech the width of main manu element use

```
#mainNav ul li {
   position:relative;
   ...
}

#mainNav .subNavContainer {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 10px;
   min-width: 100px;
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nidzix. I should have mentioned initially that I want the submenu to scale to the content, or to be a fixed width that accommodates the various nav labels. The former is my preference.

Your suggestions have worked in as much as the menu renders the same in all instances, but it also scales to 100% width automatically.

Also, for my own education, can you expand on the use the mainNav > ul?